# recognition of digits using SVM in openCV C++

Tags: svm

```
svm.train(training_mat, labels, Mat(), Mat(), params);
```

I can't understand this line in Support Vector Machine in openCV using C++.

Can anyone tell me how to put these parameters right according to my data?

Comment: Can you tell us which data?

Comment: my data are some images.. i want to recognize digits in it.

Comment: after i cropped the digit from images, i wanted to recognize it using SVM and now i can't put the right parameters in this line to make it work.                                  thank u for answering

Answer (score 0):

You have to lear the concept "feature" first. A "feature" is a tag of an object (in your case image) expressed by a single number.

First of all, you have to decide/evaluate, which features are most suitable to describe your images.

For each image you should extract a couple of same features, which will build a feature vectors.

`training_mat` contains the list of feature vectors, where each feature vector corresponds to a number in `labels` defining which object it is (e.g. image for "0")

The simpliest features to extract, which also work reasonably well with monochrome digit images - are pixels of the scaled images e.g. 16x16;